# login form on the home page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need a way to **pass a variable from one controller to the view** that has been **loaded from within another controller**.

I want to **put a login form on the homepage** and **evaluate the $error** variable to see if it is equal to 1 and based on that
display the **error message**.

controllers/posts.php:

```
<?php
class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('post');

        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    function index($start=0){

        $this->session->unset_userdata('pretrazi');
        $data['posts']=$this->post->get_posts(1,$start);

        $config['base_url']=base_url().'posts/index/';
        $config['total_rows']=$this->post->get_posts_count();
        $config['per_page']=1;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pages']=$this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('posts_index',$data);
    }

    function post($slug){

        $data['post']=$this->post->get_post($slug);
        $this->load->view('post',$data);
    }

    function new_post(){

        if($_POST){
            $data=array(
                'title'=>$_POST['title'],
                'post'=>$_POST['post'],
                'active'=>1,
                'slug' => url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE)
            );
            $this->post->insert_post($data);
            redirect(base_url().'posts/');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('new_post');
        }
    }

    function editpost($postid){

        $data['success']=0;
        if($_POST){
            $data_post=array(
                'title'=>$_POST['title'],
                'post'=>$_POST['post'],
                'slug' => url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE)
            );
            $this->post->update_post($postid,$data_post);
            $data['success']=1;
        }

        $data['post']=$this->post->get_post_by_id($postid);
        $this->load->view('edit_post',$data);
    }

    function deletepost($postid){

        $this->post->delete_post($postid);
        redirect(base_url().'posts');
    }
?>
```

controllers/users.php:

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    function login(){

        $data['error']=0;

        if($_POST){
            $this->load->model('user');
            $username=$this->input->post('username',true);
            $password=$this->input->post('password',true);
            $user=$this->user->login($username,$password);

            if(!$user){
            $data['error']=1;

            }else{
            $this->session->set_userdata('userID',$user['userID']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$user['username']);

            redirect(base_url().'posts');
            }
        }   
    }

    function logout(){

        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url().'posts');
    }
}

?>
```

views/posts_index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
<?php
  if($this->session->userdata('username')){
?>
<p>Welcome <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username')?></p>
<a href="<?=base_url()?>users/logout">Logout</a>
<?php }else{?>

<?php
if(isset($error) and $error==1){
echo "Password/username wrong";
}?>
<form action="<?=base_url()?>users/login" method="POST">
Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="container">
<h1>My blog</h1>
<?php
if(!isset($posts)){
?>
<p>There are no posts</p>
<?php
}else{
foreach($posts as $row){
?>
<h2><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>posts/post/<?php echo $row['slug']?>"><?php echo $row['title']?></a><?php if($this->session->userdata('username')){?>-<a href="<?php echo
base_url()?>posts/editpost/<?php echo $row['postID']?>">Edit</a> | <a class="delete" href="<?php echo base_url()?>posts/deletepost/<?php echo $row['postID']?>">Delete</a><?php }?></h2>
<p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($row['post']),0,200).".."?></p>
<p><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>posts/post/<?php echo $row['slug']?>">Read more</a></p>
<hr>
<?php
}
    }

?>
</div>
<?php echo $pages;?>
<script>
$(function() {

   $("a.delete").click(function() {

       return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
   });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever provide wrong login credentials or just click the login button without entering anything i get a blank page.**How can i get this $error** to
display above the form on the posts_index view which is my homepage???

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a [flashdata](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) in the session.

Try this: In your users.php controller after the login succes check set the flash data.

```
 if(!$user)
{
    $data_err  = array(
                       'log_failed' =>'Invalid Login!',
                       'log_user'   => $username
                      );
    $this->session->set_flashdata('log_status',$data_err);
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

and in the view :

```
if (null != $this->session->flashdata ( 'log_status' )) 
{
    $errorData = $this->session->flashdata ( 'log_status' );
    echo $errorData ["log_failed"];
}
```